# Setup SFTP to use public-key authentication

Tags: linux, unix, authentication, sftp, public-key

How do you setup server to server SFTP to use public-key authentication instead of user account and password?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the client you need to generate its public key and add it to server's authorized key list.

The following are the commands you can use.

**On client machine**

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -f id_dsa
mv id_dsa* ~/.ssh/
scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub USER_NAME@SERVER:~/.ssh/HOST_NAME.key
```

**On the server**

```
cat ~/.ssh/HOST_NAME.key >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Comment: Use `ssh-copy-id` instead of your `scp` + `cat` dance.

Comment: Nice, like that ssh-copy-id. I'm on a HP-UX and wish it were installed.

Comment: Oh right... I forget that not all the world uses OpenSSH.  Sad.

Comment: Can I login from unknown machine using the private key that was generated for known/configured client to communicate to server? I mean, is this private key portable & could be used to authenticate myself to server from other machines, in case of emergency needs ??

Answer (score 3):

Remember to

```
chmod 700 .ssh
```

and also

```
chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for windows users

I had a similar issue on windows so I used Putty from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

If you need to generate a public key then use:
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe

Then, when you want to automate a batch to download from the FTP server the Pageant in order to load the private key into session
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pageant.exe

Then use the PSFTP to connect and perform actions
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/psftp.exe

So here is sample code for the batch:

```
!--Loading the key to session--!
@C:\pageant.exe "C:\privatekey.ppk"
!--Calling the PSFTP.exe with the uaser and sftp address + command list file--!
@C:\psftp user@your.server.address -b C:\sftp_cmd.txt
```

Command list file (sftp_cmd.txt) will like like this:

```
mget "*.*" !--downloading every thing
!--more commands can follow here
close
```

Now, all you need to to schedule it in scheduled tasks
*I wish it was simple as unix's cron job....