# How to transfer file using sftp in ksh

Tags: ksh

I want to use script ksh with sftp but I don't know how to add password in the command **sftp user@host** ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: You'll want to use SSH public keys: http://www.jscape.com/blog/setting-up-sftp-public-key-authentication-command-line

Comment: How to use it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231514/setup-sftp-to-use-public-key-authentication